# how to convert hardcoded html site to asp mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a hard coded html website of 5 pages and want to convert it to mvc4.

what do i need to do?
Is there a tutorial or step by step guide outlining how to make .html files dynamic via MVC?

Comment: What problem do you currently have with a static HTML site that will be solved by switching to MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to want to get a basic understanding of MVC and especially the routing before you change it over - you will avoid a lot of confusion and pitfalls in the future.

Basically, all you will need to do is create Controllers (dummy, for now) for your html, and copy the html into the respective View.  This will all make sense when you understand the routing in the global.asax file.  Then I would update the links to `@Html.ActionLink` syntax and move from there - likely next extracting a `_Layout` for universal design, etc.

Basically, read a quick tutorial at minimum, or you will just frustrate yourself.

Comment: the html is not just a single file with everything. its nicely broken out into /css and /script for the js files also /images and the html is really just UI stuff.

Comment: That is good, that will make the transition easier as the js generally go into ~/Scripts/ folder and the Css into the ~/Content/ folder by default.

Answer (score 0):

If the pages have unique data on them then you could create a controller for each page, a model and a view.

If all of the the pages have similar information you could have one controller with various views.