# integrating static html/css pages to an asp.net mvc project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working for a personal project (Creating a website). I finished the design, then i converted all the pages to static html/css pages, after that i added some javascript. now I am with the final stage making the site dynamic i mean integrating the html/css pages to be an Asp.net MVC project with c# code that generates the content. even if i can tinker, but i prefer to be more methodical. so i am asking you for any guidelines how to do it ?  and what the things i need to keep in mind to make this conversion ?

Comment: This is not a specific question about an issue that you are experiencing and thus is not a good question for this website. If you have a specific issue, ask away. Provide mode details regarding the issues that you have.

Comment: @Dmitry, it's not different in nature to http://stackoverflow.com/q/13731851/1045881 or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/194014, and it's a fine question. I have the same question!

Answer (score 0):

I am going to document my experience doing this here. It's going to be a incomplete and / or incorrect answer until I'm done with the process in a few days. I'm assuming Visual Studio 2012.

1. Create a new MVC 4 Internet Application project.
2. Add a method to the home controller for each static page.
3. Right click on each method and select Add View.
4. Open the images folder in VS and delete every item (from inside VS)
5. Drag all static site images into images project folder and add to project.
6. Replace contents of Site.css with static site css.
7. Paste the html from each page into the corresponding view. Leave the `ViewBag.Title` code block alone.

(still incomplete)